# BigQuery EXTRACT HOUR provides unexpected result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the EXTRACT function of bigquery to extract an hour from a column of type TIMESTAMP, that provide an UTC time.

The problem is there is an inconsistency between the expected result and the real result.
There is normally a delta of four hours between UTC and NY time.

Here is the query and the result:

```sql
select reservation_time, EXTRACT(HOUR from reservation_time AT TIME ZONE "America/New_York") 
from matview.resview

#
# EXPECTED
#
2021-06-06 02:00:00    22
2021-06-06 02:00:00    22
2021-06-06 02:00:00    22
2021-06-06 01:30:00    21


#
# REAL RESULT
#
2021-06-06 02:00:00    20
2021-06-06 02:00:00    20
2021-06-06 02:00:00    20
2021-06-06 01:30:00    19
```

Edit:

See an other SQL Query and its output:

```sql
select FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T %Z", reservation_time), reservation_time 
from matview.resview


#
# OUTPUT
#

2021-03-11 14:30:00 UTC 2021-03-11 15:30:00
2021-04-09 13:30:00 UTC 2021-04-09 15:30:00
2020-07-23 20:30:00 UTC 2020-07-23 22:30:00
2020-07-23 21:00:00 UTC 2020-07-23 23:00:00
2020-07-23 20:00:00 UTC 2020-07-23 22:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a different default timezone and see times not in UTC.
Try this query instead to compare UTC times with extracted hour:

```
select
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T %Z", reservation_time),
  EXTRACT(HOUR from reservation_time AT TIME ZONE "America/New_York")
from matview.resview
```

Comment: Yes you are right ! Thanks for providing a way to check it. Probably the problem comes from DBeaver